# Nodemon stopped working

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I use nodemon to work with node.js. All is fine. Today I typed nodemon app.js and it doesn't know the command.

I reinstalled with npm install -g nodemon.
It reinstalled without any error.
It still doesn't work.

under:

```
user\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

I removed all files depending nodemon.
Again I reinstalled but it still doesnt know the command. What happend and what to do?

```
Windows 8.1
```

Comment: I added `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm` to my PATH its working again, but I don't know why I worked before

Answer (score 0):

Open and run the command line window as administrator and run the command npm install -g nodemon